# JDBC: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/EarthDS

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jdbc, derby

I am trying to deploy my project using `maven-cargo-plugin` and `pom.xml` looks like

```
<properties>
        <maven.cargo.version>1.4.8</maven.cargo.version>
        <datasource.jndi>java:/jdbc/EarthDS</datasource.jndi>
        <h2.user>sa</h2.user>
        <h2.driver>org.h2.Driver</h2.driver>
        <datasource.url>jdbc:h2:${project.build.directory}/earth</datasource.url>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.12</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <resteasy-client.version>3.0.8.Final</resteasy-client.version>
        <jackson-mapper-asl.version>1.9.13</jackson-mapper-asl.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.4</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <derby.port>1527</derby.port>
        <datasource.user>APP</datasource.user>
        <datasource.password>nonemptypassword</datasource.password>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.learner</groupId>
            <artifactId>services</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.learner</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.learner</groupId>
            <artifactId>database</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.learner</groupId>
            <artifactId>database</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy-client.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-mapper-asl.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.11.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.carlspring.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>derby-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>${derby.port}</port>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-derby</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-derby</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <groups>
                        com.learner.persistence.harness.PreIntegration
                    </groups>
                    <excludedGroups>
                        com.learner.persistence.harness.Integration
                    </excludedGroups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <groups>
                        com.learner.persistence.harness.Integration
                    </groups>
                    <excludedGroups>
                        com.learner.persistence.harness.PreIntegration
                    </excludedGroups>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.cargo.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>wildfly8x</containerId>
                        <dependencies combine.children="append">
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <systemProperties combine.children="append">
                            <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
                            </hibernate.dialect>
                        </systemProperties>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                            <cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>
                                cargo.datasource.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver|
                                cargo.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:${derby.port}/integrationDB|
                                cargo.datasource.jndi=${datasource.jndi}|
                                cargo.datasource.username=${datasource.user}|
                                cargo.datasource.password=${datasource.password}
                            </cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <properties>
                                <context>earth</context>
                            </properties>
                            <pingURL>http://localhost:9090/earth/rest/hello</pingURL>
                            <pingTimeout>36000</pingTimeout>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-container</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-container</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:36:43,203 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (default task-14) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:304)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:311)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:246)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:1144)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:446)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getTransactionNewConnection(AbstractPool.java:553)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:429)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:379)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:422)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:513)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:142)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPAQuery.java:195) [querydsl-jpa-3.4.3.jar:]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:243) [querydsl-jpa-3.4.3.jar:]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.learner.persistence.PersonQueries.getPersons(PersonQueries.java:24) [persistence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.learner.business.manager.PersonManager.getPersons(PersonManager.java:34) [business-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at
```

Has anyone seen this issue before? I am lost in this error

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use Derby? Or H2? You seem to have parts of both databases mixed together in your project. Your datasource.url starts "jdbc:h2:..." which looks like an H2 connection url, not a Derby connection URL.

Comment: I'm using `Derby` see `cargo.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:${derby.port}/integrationDB|`